# Batch Create folders based on file names excluding parenthesis and brackets

Tags: batch, windows-10

I have thousands of files with the following structure:

```
Sample1 (43643) [3235]
Sample1 (32352) [6432]
Sample1 (35346) [4364]
```

I am trying to batch create folders based on the file name excluding the brackets and parenthesis and move all similarly named files into that folder like this:

```
Sample1\Sample1 (43643) [3235]
Sample1\Sample1 (32352) [6432]
Sample1\Sample1 (35346) [4364]
```

Any Ideas how to do this?  Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:**

**@beatcracker** I was able to get it to work with the example filenames but here are the actual files names I am using (which did not work):

```
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a10].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a11].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a12].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a2].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a3].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a4].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a5].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a6].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a7].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a8].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a9].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][a].adf
1st Division Manager (1992)(Codemasters)[cr NMS][h KTS].adf
3D Construction Kit II r2.01 (1992)(Domark)(Disk 1 of 2)[h Ministry][construction kit].adf
3D Construction Kit II r2.01 (1992)(Domark)(Disk 2 of 2)[construction kit].adf
3D Construction Kit II r2.03 (1992)(Domark)(FR)(Disk 1 of 2)[construction kit].adf
3D Construction Kit II r2.03 (1992)(Domark)(FR)(Disk 2 of 2)[construction kit].adf
```

Comment: I would like to add that I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the PowerShell version. Works for the single folder, uses regex to match file names. Just edit `$OrigFolder`/`$NewFolder` accordingly:

```
# Folder where files are stored
$OrigFolder = 'C:\MyFolder'

# Folder where sorted files will be stored.
# It will be created if not exists.
$NewFolder = 'C:\MyFolder_Sorted'

# Folder, where files with empty part of the name will be stored
# Example: file "(1992)(Domark)(FR)(Disk 2 of 2)[construction kit].adf"
# will be moved to ".\Sorted\Unknown" folder
$UnknownFolder = 'Unknown'

# Regex to match filenames
$Regex = '^\s*(.*?)\s*\('

# Loop through files in directory, skip folders
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $OrigFolder | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
    ForEach-Object {
        if($_.BaseName -match $Regex){

            # If first part of the file name is empty,
            # move it to the 'Unknown' folder
            if(!$Matches[1]){
                $ChildPath = $UnknownFolder
            } else {
                $ChildPath =  $Matches[1]
            }

            # Generate new folder name
            $FolderName = Join-Path -Path $NewFolder -ChildPath $ChildPath

            # Create folder if not exists
            if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $FolderName -PathType Container)){
                $null = New-Item -Path $FolderName -ItemType Directory
            }

            # Basic logging
            Write-Host "$($_.FullName) -> $FolderName"

            # Move file
            Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination $FolderName
        }
}
```

Save it as `MoveFiles.ps1` and run in PowerShell console like this: `.\MoveFiles.ps1`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response.  I followed the instructions carefully, editing the folder paths on lines 1 & 2, then ran the script as .\MoveFiles.ps1 in PowerShell but nothing happened...

Comment: @Jonathan Maybe regex is too strict (script works for me with your example filenames). It will match only the filenames as in your example. Could you post actual filename?

Comment: I was able to get it to work with the example filenames but here are the actual files names I am working with (please see above)

Comment: @Jonathan So, basically, you want folder name to be anything until first `(`? Example: `1st Division Manager`, `3D Construction Kit II r2.03`, `3D Construction Kit II r2.01`? Then see my updated answer.